# CSS is being rendered in an HTML body

Tags: html, css

My team uses Sendgrid to handle email processes. We have a a way to process certain data and render it with string interpolation. Some emails have been rendering some CSS in the email body and I'm trying to figure out why.

I grabbed some of the HTML that's being passed in for a specific email which looks like this:

```html
<meta content="text/html; charset=us-ascii" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
<meta content="Microsoft Word 15 (filtered medium)" name="Generator" />
<style>
    &lt;
    !--

    /* Font Definitions */
    @font-face {
        font-family: "Cambria Math";
        panose-1: 2 4 5 3 5 4 6 3 2 4;
    }

    @font-face {
        font-family: Calibri;
        panose-1: 2 15 5 2 2 2 4 3 2 4;
    }

    /* Style Definitions */
    p.MsoNormal,
    li.MsoNormal,
    div.MsoNormal {
        margin: 0in;
        font-size: 11.0pt;
        font-family: "Calibri", sans-serif;
    }

    span.EmailStyle17 {
        mso-style-type: personal-compose;
        font-family: "Calibri", sans-serif;
        color: windowtext;
    }

    .MsoChpDefault {
        mso-style-type: export-only;
        font-family: "Calibri", sans-serif;
    }

    @page WordSection1 {
        size: 8.5in 11.0in;
        margin: 1.0in 1.0in 1.0in 1.0in;
    }

    div.WordSection1 {
        page: WordSection1;
    }

    --&gt;
</style>
<!--[if gte mso 9]><xml> <o:shapedefaults v:ext="edit" spidmax="1026" /> </xml><![endif]--><!--[if gte mso 9]><xml> <o:shapelayout v:ext="edit"> <o:idmap v:ext="edit" data="1" /> </o:shapelayout></xml><![endif]-->
<div class="WordSection1">
    <p class="MsoNormal">test<o:p></o:p>
    </p>
</div>
```

There rendered text in the body of the email looks like this:

```
- 





/* Font Definitions */
@font-face
{font-family:"Cambria Math";
panose-1:2 4 5 3 5 4 6 3 2 4;}
@font-face
{font-family:Calibri;
panose-1:2 15 5 2 2 2 4 3 2 4;}
@font-face
{font-family:Verdana;
panose-1:2 11 6 4 3 5 4 4 2 4;}
/* Style Definitions */
p.MsoNormal, li.MsoNormal, div.MsoNormal
{margin:0in;
font-size:11.0pt;
font-family:"Calibri",sans-serif;}
a:link, span.MsoHyperlink
{mso-style-priority:99;
color:blue;
text-decoration:underline;}
span.EmailStyle21
{mso-style-type:personal-reply;
font-family:"Calibri",sans-serif;
color:windowtext;}
.MsoChpDefault
{mso-style-type:export-only;
font-size:10.0pt;}
@page WordSection1
{size:8.5in 11.0in;
margin:1.0in 1.0in 1.0in 1.0in;}
div.WordSection1
{page:WordSection1;}
-->



test
```

Does the HTML here look wrong or are there any typos that I can't see?

Comment: your style element isn't rendered as is but its content is like regular content to be rendered. You have html comments inside your style encoded as html entities that when rendered on the body (as the output you showed) shows correctly... the very first &lt; isn't showing up and I have no idea why, the ! is not appearing at all and you can see only the double dash. The fake closing comment shows correctly because the html entities get decoded correctly when rendered. Now the question is why you have your style element cluttered with those fake comments? Maybe that's a culprit?

Comment: the question I ask to better understand before any further step is taken, is: did you try to clean up your style element before doing anything else? and after that what's the WHOLE situation of the html? do you see consistency in the whole document?

Comment: @DiegoD Good question, I think those character are probably not being stripped out correctly. Gonna use regex to remove them from within the <style> tags and see if that works